# Update graphics in Spring MVC with Echarts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, echarts

i have some problem. I don't know how to update graphics data using radio buttons in html

Java code:

```
package com.lavosami.controllers;

import com.lavosami.data.Data;
import com.lavosami.data.DataBase;
import com.lavosami.data.JSON;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import static com.lavosami.data.DataBase.dataBase;

@Controller
public class ChartController {
    String name = "Hydra-L (01)";
    String value = "Temperature";
    int mode = 0;

    @GetMapping("/chart")
    public String getChartData(Model model) {
        JSON.filesParse();

        // --------------------------------------------
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Data data : dataBase.values()) {
            if (!items.contains(data.getName())) {
                items.add(data.getName());
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(items);
        model.addAttribute("chartItems", items);
        // --------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("Temperature");
        values.add("Pressure");
        values.add("Humidity");
        model.addAttribute("chartValues", values);
        // --------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------
        List<String> parse = new ArrayList<>();
        parse.add("JSON");
        parse.add("CSV");
        model.addAttribute("chartParser", parse);
        // --------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------
        List<String> averaging = new ArrayList<>();
        averaging.add("All values");
        averaging.add("Average by hour");
        averaging.add("Average by 3 hours");
        averaging.add("Average by 24 hours");
        averaging.add("Min/Max values in every day");
        model.addAttribute("chartAveraging", averaging);
        // --------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------
        Map<String, Object> chartData = new HashMap<>();

        Map<Date, Double> data = DataBase.averagedValue(name, value, mode);

        List<String> xData = data.keySet().stream()
                .filter(date -> !Double.isNaN(data.get(date)))
                .map(date -> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))
                .toList();

        List<String> yData = data.values().stream()
                .filter(value -> !Double.isNaN(value))
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .toList();

        chartData.put("xData", xData.toString());
        chartData.put("yData", yData.toString());

        model.addAttribute("chartData", chartData);

        return "chart";
        // --------------------------------------------
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.2.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: #5670BC;
        }
        body {
            font-family: "Helvetica", "Sans-Serif";
            color: #65666B;
        }
        .fieldset-container {
          display: flex;
        }
        .fieldset-container fieldset {
          flex: 1;
        }
        input {
            margin: 0.4rem;
        }

        .radio-container {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
          }

          /* Стили для fieldset */
          fieldset {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: inline-block;
          }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Weather's charts</h1>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Select device:</legend>
        <div th:each="item : ${chartItems}" class="radio-container">
            <input type="checkbox" th:id="${item}" name="item" th:value="${item}" th:checked="${item == 'Hydra-L (01)'}">
            <label th:for="${item}" th:text="${item}"></label>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<div class="fieldset-container">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select values type:</legend>
        <div th:each="value : ${chartValues}">
            <input type="radio" th:id="${value}" name="value" th:value="${value}" th:checked="${value == 'Temperature'}">
            <label th:for="${value}" th:text="${value}"></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select type of parse file:</legend>
        <div th:each="parse : ${chartParser}">
            <input type="radio" th:id="${parse}" name="parse" th:value="${parse}" th:checked="${parse == 'JSON'}">
            <label th:for="${parse}" th:text="${parse}"></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select averaging:</legend>
        <div th:each="averaging : ${chartDiapason}">
            <input type="radio" th:id="${averaging}" name="averaging" th:value="${averaging}" th:checked="${averaging == 'All values'}">
            <label th:for="${averaging}" th:text="${averaging}"></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<div id="categoryChartContainer" style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px"></div>
<div id="boundaryGapChartContainer" style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData = {
        xData: "[[${chartData.xData}]]",
        yData: "[[${chartData.yData}]]"
    };

    var xData = chartData.xData.split(',');
    var yData = chartData.yData.split(',');

    var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('categoryChartContainer'));
    var option = {
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            data: xData
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        series: [{
            data: yData,
            type: 'line'
        }]
    };
    chart.setOption(option);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData = {
        xData: "[[${chartData.xData}]]",
        yData: "[[${chartData.yData}]]"
    };

    var xData = chartData.xData.split(',');
    var yData = chartData.yData.split(',');

    var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('boundaryGapChartContainer'));
    var option = {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: xData
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: yData,
          type: 'bar'
        }
      ]
    };
    chart.setOption(option);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My code needs to show graphics of weather condition, like in the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35b7U.png)

When user select any radio button or check button, graphics should update

I tried to write some function using RequestMapping, but bumped into the fact, that i'm stupid, so nothing works